# Find minimum/maximum within same column of dataframes in a list R

Tags: r, dataframe, min

I have 323 `data.frame`s in a `list` called `mrns`. In each `data.frame`, there is a variable called `raw.Systolic`. What I need to do is find the minimum/maximum `raw.Systolic` among ALL 323 `data.frame`s. I can output the minima for each `data.frame`, but that's not what I need.

The closest I've gotten so far is outputting the list of minima for each file and trying to find a way to find the minima of that output, but I don't know how.

This is what I have so far:

```
for (i in 1:323) {
  print(min(mrns[[i]]$raw.Systolic, na.rm=TRUE))
}
```

Which outputs:

```
[1] 86
[1] 109
[1] 114
[1] 104
[1] 115
...etc until 323 maximums are listed
```

When I do:

```
for (i in 1:323) {
  mins <- min(mrns[[i]]$raw.Systolic, na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

I get:

```
> mins
[1] 129
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: `min(sapply(mrns,function(x)min(x$raw.Systolic)))`, or for both max and min, `range(c(sapply(mrns,function(x)range(x$raw.Systolic))))`

Comment: @MichaelChirico Why do you use the inner `min`?

Comment: @Roland I suppose that's not necessary huh. Don't have sample data so couldn't bench test anything.

Comment: @Roland on second thought if the `data.frame`s differ in `nrow`, `sapply` will return a list and the outer min will no longer work.

Comment: @MichaelChirico The minimum of the minima is the same as the minimum of all values. So, yes, you can definitely save the calls to `min` inside the loop.

Comment: Your for loop isn't working because `mins` is being overwritten. Change to `mins[i] <- min(mrns[[...`

Comment: @Roland see my answer for a solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
min(unlist(lapply(mrns, function(x) min(x$raw.Systolic, na.rm=T))))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with:

```
#minima:
do.call("min",sapply(mrns,getElement,name="raw.Systolic"))

#ranges
do.call("range",sapply(mrns,getElement,name="raw.Systolic"))

#NA-proof
do.call("min",c(sapply(mrns,getElement,name="raw.Systolic"),na.rm=T))
```

Note that `getElement` is just the extraction operator `$` in function form, i.e. `x$y` is the same as `getElement(object=x,name="y")`.

If you know that all the elements of `mrns` have the same number of rows, just use `min(sapply(...))` instead.

Since `sapply` is likely to return a `list` given each element of `mrns` likely has a different number of rows, we use `do.call` with allows us to pass a `list` to `min` and `range`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I get `[1] NA NA` when I run this. Marked a different response as answer, but thank you for responding! I appreciate the help.

Comment: @nchimato see edit for how to add the `na.rm=T` argument to the above. note that the other answer is likely inefficient as it calls `min` 323 times in the inner loop and again when done.